# How to detect mobile and tablet using CSS or JavaScript regardless of brands?

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, mobile, css

Basically what I'm trying to do is have 3 css stylesheets for desktop, mobile, and tablet.
And I don't care if it is ipad or samsung galaxy tab as long as I know it is a tablet, so that I just apply tablet css to it. Same as iphone or Nexus which I don't care either. I just care about the dimension basically. That would be good if JQuery Mobile could do this.

I know there is lots of code for detecting iphone, ipad, and etc, hope my post still makes sense.

Thanks.

Comment: After more than 2 years, can you tell if someone here provided you an acceptable answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like using [CSS media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to create a [responsive design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) may be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can check great article on [SmashingMagazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/) about [media queries and browser detection](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/03/how-to-build-a-mobile-website/#mobile-stylesheets)

If you dig there some more, you will find more useful info.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10364620/450399

He uses css to check screensize and sets a HTML element and reference the css in javascript to determine if it's a "mobile/tablet" device.

You can also have a look at [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) :) It's really magic!

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [device.js](http://matthewhudson.me/projects/device.js/) and [mobile-detect.js](https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js/)